# Is it possible to build the same IOS app on different Mac Machines

Tags: ios, flutter-ios, ios-app-signing

I'm new to IOS app development and I don't have a Mac machine. But I'm planning to get virtual Mac Machine from https://www.macincloud.com and start developing. I think when build and publish the app Xcode should automatically manage app signing and provisioning. right ?

Let's say I found better virtual machine in the future ( eg: AWS MAC ), is it possible to build and publish the same app on different virtual machine ? Now on the different machine, XCode will be different and still ill be able to publish the same app without any issues ? ( will it be any signing and provisioning issues ? )

The same will happened when I get the physical Mac machine and it will have different Xcode... still ill be able to build the same app and publish to the save account ?

pls explain

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure XCode is the same version on all machines, otherwise you could run into strange bugs, but it is easy to develop the same project on multiple machines.  You can either keep all of your source code in a repository like Github and use xcode connect to it and pull/commit as necessary or you can sign into the different Macs with your Apple ID and store the xcode project files in an iCloud synced folder and just work on them from there (I do this a lot and it works fine).

In xcode just use your developer account as the development team of the project across machines and you should be fine, but you need not worry about this at all if you're new to iOS development, just focus on building your app and when you're actually ready to publish it (or close to it) then sign up for your Apple Developer Account and add it to xcode.  You won't be able to easily test your app on a physical device until you have your dev account, but you can use the simulator instead for most of the development life of your project.